# Wondering, If there is a Guide out there

Tags: 15.10

Is there a Ubuntu Guide that shows all the Commands and how to operate Ubuntu?... I am now installing the Ubuntu And am need you all help, at the moment.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would check the Ubuntu [Desktop Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/index.html).

Here is all their [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/).